How to make `__getitems__` return a dict?
In torch's Dataset, on top of the obligatory __getitem__ method, you can implement the __getitems__ method.
In my case __getitem__ returns a dict, but I can't figure out how to do the same with __getitems__.
class StackOverflowDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {'item': self._data[idx], 'whatever': idx*self._data[idx]+3}

    def __getitems__(self, idxs):
        return {'item': self._data[idxs], 'whatever': idxs*self._data[idxs]+3}
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)

dataset = StackOverflowDataset(np.random.random(5))
for X in DataLoader(dataset, 2):
    print(X)
    break

If I comment out __getitems__ it works, but leaving it there raises a KeyError: 0.
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[182], line 15
     12         return len(self._data)
     14 dataset = StackOverflowDataset(np.random.random(5))
---> 15 for X in DataLoader(dataset, 2):
     16     print(X)
     17     break

File ~/recommenders/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:630, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    627 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    628     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    629     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 630 data = self._next_data()
    631 self._num_yielded += 1
    632 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    633         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    634         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/recommenders/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:673, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    671 def _next_data(self):
    672     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 673     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    674     if self._pin_memory:
    675         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~/recommenders/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:55, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     53 else:
     54     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 55 return self.collate_fn(data)

File ~/recommenders/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:317, in default_collate(batch)
    256 def default_collate(batch):
    257     r"""
    258     Take in a batch of data and put the elements within the batch into a tensor with an additional outer dimension - batch size.
    259 
   (...)
    315         >>> default_collate(batch)  # Handle `CustomType` automatically
    316     """
--> 317     return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)

File ~/recommenders/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:137, in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    109 def collate(batch, *, collate_fn_map: Optional[Dict[Union[Type, Tuple[Type, ...]], Callable]] = None):
    110     r"""
    111     General collate function that handles collection type of element within each batch.
    112 
   (...)
    135         for the dictionary of collate functions as `collate_fn_map`.
    136     """
--> 137     elem = batch[0]
    138     elem_type = type(elem)
    140     if collate_fn_map is not None:

KeyError: 0


__getitems__ should return a sequence of something, not a dict. If your element type is a dict, that doesn't magically allow transposing list[dict[...]] into dict[str, list[...]]. From docs: This method accepts list of indices of samples of batch and returns list of samples.

getitems is supposed to take a list of indices and return a list of items. Your implementation completely disregards this. See the documentation for Dataset  (e.g., in the code: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#Dataset)

That's because pytorch tries to access data by index, starting from 0.
Official documentation says:

Subclasses could also optionally implement getitems(), for speedup
batched samples loading. This method accepts list of indices of
samples of batch and returns list of samples.

In other words, __getitems__ should return list, not a dict.

If getitems returns a list of dicts, that is then transformed into a dict of lists, then where are the batched samples? If I have to map to get a dictionary for every item, its just as inefficient as calling getitem multiple times then.

It's not supposed to be used like this, you should control batches, like here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataset.html#Dataset

I mean Dataset + Dataloader. The dataset returns 64 dictionaries, and then the DataLoader returns a dictionary with tensors of size 64. Isn't there any way to speed it up and make the dataset directly pass the tensors to the dataloader? I profiled my model and this is taking over 80% of the train time.

Now it looks like this comment should be your original question, not about __getitems__. Ideally, it would be good to see the whole code, but from what I see, you're already using some sort of batching. And yes, __getitem__ executes once per item, so maybe you want to load items into your training model in some other way?

I think it is a completely different question. The __getitems__ returning a list of dicts part worked, so i will set the question as solved.
